# ProcessOut integration without composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to integrate processout but they only seem to support composer integration.

https://github.com/ProcessOut/processout-php

How would I integrate this just by uploading the /src/ folder into my project?

```
<?php
// Load dependencies
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiate ProcessOut
$processout = new \ProcessOut\ProcessOut();
$processout->setProjectId('<project-id>');
$processout->setProjectSecret('<project-key>');

// Set this project as the default one for the current request
\ProcessOut\ProcessOut::setDefault($processout);
?>
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the autoloader? You could possibly`require_once /src/ProcessOut/ProcessOut.php;` but you're going to require every single script it requires more than likely. That's 'the beauty of the autoloader, it does it for you.

Comment: I'm a total idiot and I fear change.

Comment: But you're honest and that goes a long way! Check out the autoloading section here to get started: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: I don't mind loading all the files manually. But when I did that I got error 500 :(

Comment: Do you have access to your PHP error_log? My best guess is that it immediately needs access to another file that needs to be manually required. You could also put `ini_set('display_errors', on);error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script if you don't have access to the error log.

Comment: ^^ I see in the posted code you use `require` rather than `require_once`, and that would be a likely source of 500 errors as well.

Comment: I'll try that one minute

Comment: Ah, it seems to have loaded all the files - so I literally loaded every file.....will it work now do you think?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'anlutro\cURL\cURL' not found in /var/www/html/src/processout/ProcessOut.php on line 47

Comment: I do have CURL installed but it seems to have run into a problem?

Comment: That error follows from not having installed the dependencies of ProcessOut itself (in this case the package `anlutro/curl`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring that Composer is not an autoloader generator, but first and foremost a dependency manager. If you look at the [`composer.json` file of the ProcessOut](https://github.com/ProcessOut/processout-php/blob/master/composer.json) package you see:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "anlutro/curl": "1.4"
  },
```

The last line is a package it depends on itself, and that you'll be missing out when not using Composer. You could theoretically load and include all dependencies recursively yourself, but in the end - just [get composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) and let it do its work.

Answer (score 0):

They have a php release where you only have to load autoload.php:

https://github.com/ProcessOut/processout-php/releases